# Ruby on Rails :before_filter => :only_when_user_is_logged_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Ruby on Rails, I want to before filter an action but only when users are logged in.

How is this possible?

Comment: Why is there still a bounty on this question. Ah, this is so noob to me now!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you're asking how to **run** a before filter only if a user is logged in. There is no built-in semantic for this, but it's easy enough to inline:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :do_something

  def do_something
    if logged_in?
      # the stuff you want to do
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Has it been deprecated in rails 4 ?

Answer (score 18):

```
before_filter :only_when_user_is_logged_in, :only => :the_action
```

Or for multiple

```
before_filter :only_when_user_is_logged_in, :only => [:the_action, :another_action]
```

On the flip side, you can also provide an `:except => :this_action` option

Comment: This is the canonical pattern, per the Rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters

Answer (score 11):

Before filters take an optional block which is passed the current controller instance
so you could do something like this:

```
before_filter :do_stuff, lambda { |controller| controller.logged_in? }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really don't want the `before_filter` executing for anyone other than logged in users consider using [`#skip_before_filter`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html#M000533) in your authentication filter. For instance if when you're checking if users are logged in in your authentication filter, if authentication fails, merely call `skip_before_filter :filter_for_logged_in_users_only`.

Other than that you can simply test if the user is logged in before executing the member only filter. For example:

```
def filter_for_logged_in_users_only
  return true unless current_user && logged_in?
  #rest of the logic
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using restful authentication, it's just `before_filter :login_required`.  If you are using your own authentication framework, you can create a method in application.rb that returns true if the user is logged in or redirects to the login page otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
class LoginsController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_filter :require_login, :only => [:new, :create]

end
```

Comment: Oops, <br>,&nbsp; inside controller. May be you are using your own new invented editor.