# Routing and Forms for a Rails app authentication system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having trouble understanding how to craft a Rails application that follows the following scheme:

The site is composed primarily of 'protected' interior paths which require the user be authenticated, in addition to one or two unprotected 'static' pages and a login page served directly from '/' (`root_path`).

I want users to generally follow the flow that they log in by going to `root_path`, and any attempt to access a protected page while unauthenticated sends them back to `root_path`. When the user logs in on the form in `root_path`, they get sent to `home_path` (even if they had been sent to `root_path` via some other page's protection - ie., no smart forwarding. I may add that later.)

Additionally, trying to browse to `root_path` while already authenticated should immediately forward the request to `home_path`. `home_path`'s page will include a link to log out, the effect of which should immediately send the user to `root_path`.

My question:

What would the routes.rb entries look like to set this up? Assuming I have a `Users` controller and a `Sessions` controller, and assuming that I already have command-line authentication (via the irb console) working, what is the correct combination of routes and controller methods that gets this system working? I'm very confused!

---

In case it helps, here is what I have so far, but I'm so lost that I can't even get this in to a working state to test it.

I have a routes file that looks like:

```
MyAppRails::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  root to: "sessions#new"
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
  match "/home" => 'users#home'
end
```

The UsersController only has a `home` method, and the SessionsController has `new`, `create`, and `destroy` methods.

I'm particularly stuck in that I don't know where to send the sign-in form to - I figure it should point at `sessions#new` somehow but I don't really get how that works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to change your routes, as a `before_filter` should be placed in each controller where you want to restrict access to logged in users.  A `:login_required` method could be called to check if a user is logged in, otherwise, redirect them to your public page.

Generally, I keep the root as a separate controller, site_controller, or something similar.  I also make my login path `sessions#new` and use my `before_filter` methods to manage redirecting guests that haven't logged in.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895645/ruby-on-rails-before-filter-only-when-user-is-logged-in) may help you.

Comment: Thanks - what should be the action of my 'form_tag' to log in, though?

Comment: The goal is to create a new session for the user, so `sessions#create` would be the target path.

Comment: Thanks again - can I simply use `form_tag('sessions#create')`? No, right?

Comment: No, that's just the match syntax.  You've already mapped `sessions#create` via the resources.  So, you could write `form_tag(sessions_path)`.

Comment: Just `sessions_path`? It seems like that couldn't possibly be enough information. How does it know what URL to generate? Heck, even *I* don't know what URL it should generate.

Comment: Rails follows the REST pattern for new, create, update, delete, destroy, index, and show routes.  Check out this [cheatsheet](http://topfunky.com/clients/peepcode/REST-cheatsheet.pdf) for examples of the REST routes.

Comment: Also use a before_filter `no_user_required` for the `root_path` if you don't want a user to be logged in here. See the documentation for `authlogic` for examples of this